# How to know the space occupied by each field in Solr

Tags: optimization, solr, indexing, size, field

our Solr index file is about 30G and we want to do some optimization to reduce the size.

Then how to know the space occupied by each field?

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://code.google.com/p/luke/
Luke would help you to analyze your index with the fields and terms and probably the percentage of the field size in the index.

Also some of the other questions :-
 1. Is your index optimized ?
 2. Revisit your configuration for the Indexed fields, stored fields, multiple copies of the same fields, term vectors and norm.
 3. Taking a look at the terms on your index and identifying stopwords or common words.